# Creating pagination links with search parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I want to know how to approach implementing pagination with user input as search parameters. I understand the basics of pagination without user input and have no trouble doing that, it's when user input comes in that it confuses me. I don't know how to make the page-number links use the correct query based on what has been searched.

For example the basic idea:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="id" placeholder="ID">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
<button id="btn_search">Search</button>

<div id="search_results"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#btn_search").on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'process.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id: $("input[name=id]").val(), name: $("input[name=name]").val()},
            success: function(result) {
                $("#search_results").html(result);
            }
        });
});
```

**PHP**

```
// Grab submitted search parameters and store in variable
    if (isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])) {
        $id = $_POST["id"];
    } else {
        $id = null;
    }
    if (isset($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
    } else {
        $name = null;
    }
    $count_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users";
    // Code here to get total row count for pagination
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? AND name = ?";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('is', $id, $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    // Dump as table
```

**I'm thinking the right approach is something like this:**

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="paginate.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&name=<?php echo $name; ?>"></a></li>
    <li><a href="paginate.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&name=<?php echo $name; ?>"></a></li>
</ul>
```

And then include one more parameter for the page number via a for loop.

Is it safe to do this with some client-side input validation? And do I have a valid approach?

**EDIT**

Naveed's answer was helpful so I'll mark it as answered. This article: https://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/php-tutorial-searching-and-pagination/ helped me out a lot with understanding how to do this. It is old but explains everything well. I ended up using the  tags to pass back the query parameters.

Comment: Use jquery datatable if it fits for your issue, it will do everything automatically for you!

Comment: Although I definitely could do that ... I would love to learn how to hand code it myself!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set few variables as hidden in form.

Number of records per page

Offset of records

Then you need to get number of pages and generate links in HTML

In PHP file :

```
$return['total'] = $rs->num_rows;
$return['records']=$rs;
echo json_encode($return);

<ul>
    <li><a href="#2" class="pagination">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3" class="pagination">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then in JQuery

```
$('a.pagination').click(function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
    // now here you need to get data from process.php and pass the page variables or calculate the offset like page 2 seems offset 21 to 40 based on limit
});
```

Comment: Question in regards to your jQuery comment ... how would I get the search parameters from process.php into that click function?

Comment: You need to return from PHP an array including total number of records. In HTML, you can set count into hidden field and the array of records in a table.

Comment: I think I get that part. But for example if  say I search "5" for the ID, and I search "Tim" for the name. Then it returns the results. When I click on a.pagination, how do I pass those same query parameters "5" and "Tim" to generate the correct next page?

Comment: for that, you need to make array of searched elements and then pass again to pagination request.

Comment: I updated my question with an article link. This answer was helpful too so thanks!